# Why does Nightwatch / Selenium give me a 'Connection reset' error?

Tags: node.js, selenium, nightwatch.js

I'm using Ubuntu Linux, Selenium 2.53, Nightwatch.js 0.9.

When running my test with the given nightwatch.json I get a 'connection reset' error from Selenium, even though Selenium says it starts successfully.  **What am I doing wrong?**

[image]