# Why does Nightwatch start a Selenium server?

Tags: selenium, nightwatch.js

The Selenium docs say:

> If your browser and tests will all run on the same machine, and your
>   tests only use the WebDriver API, then you do not need to run the
>   Selenium-Server; WebDriver will run the browser directly.

So why does Nightwatch even use the server?  Whenever I try to run my tests they first say `Starting Selenium Server`.

I imagine my tests would be faster without starting a server for each. Is there a way to turn it off? Currently Selenium isn't even working for me: [Why does Nightwatch / Selenium give me a 'Connection reset' error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38657508/why-does-nightwatch-selenium-give-me-a-connection-reset-error)

Answer (score 1):

Nightwatch will send a http request to the webdriver server to run your tests on a web browser. You can go over the way Nightwatch.js works in detail here:
http://nightwatchjs.org/getingstarted

Nightwatch is just a task runner. You still need a server along with the task runner to actually execute your tasks. That's where Webdriver comes in. Selenium is one of the most popular Webdriver out there and is stable when paired with Nightwatch tasks. Whether to use a standalone server or not is optional and up to you.